# 10th derivative by MacLaurin

Tags: euler-maclaurin

I'm sorry for my language. English is not my first language.

I'm trying to find $$f^{(10)}(0)\;\;\text{when}\;\;f(x)=\frac{1}{2+x}$$ by using MacLaurin. The answer is: $$f^{(10)}(0)=\frac{10!}{2^{11}}$$

Wolfram Alpha gives the formula:
$$\frac{1}{2+x}=\sum_{n=0}^n x^n (-1)^n2^{-1-n}.$$
How do I get from
$\dfrac{1}{2+x}$
to
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^n x^n (-1)^n2^{-1-n}$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you know that $$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series is a [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) one: for any $x$ such that $|x|<2$,
$$\frac{1}{2+x}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-(-x/2)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-x/2)^k$$
On the other hand, the given function is analytic in $|x|<2$ with MacLaurin expansion
$$\frac{1}{2+x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k.$$
Hence, it follows that
$$\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=\frac{(-1/2)^k}{2}\implies f^{(k)}(0)=\frac{(-1)^k k!}{2^{k+1}}.$$

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to reply, thank you!

I get the first part, but i dont understand how this work. Do you have time to explain it?

Hence, it follows that$$
$\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=\frac{(-1/2)^k}{2}\implies f^{(k)}(0)=\frac{(-1)^k k!}{2^{k+1}}.$$

Comment: Do you mean this: $\frac{(-1/2)^k}{2}=\frac{(-1)^k}{2\cdot 2^k}$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac {1}{(2+x)}= \frac{1}{2} \frac {1}{(1+x/2)}= \frac{1}{2} \frac {1}{(1-(-x/2))}$$